# SharePoint Calendar overlay error

Tags: error, calendar

I am working on the SharePoint Calendar overlay, but it shows the error The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm

How can I fix that

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize"'. (f0a8139e-c0ec-4000-3ccf-609d07375256)

for the SharePoint calendar exchange overlay?

Comment: are you trying this for SharePoint online or On premise?

Answer (score 1):

["The HTTP request is unauthorized" error in a SharePoint Online calendar after you configure a calendar overlay to Exchange Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2997170/-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-error-in-a-sharepoint-online-calenda)

Consider the following scenario:

1. You have a calendar overlay in Microsoft SharePoint Online.

2. You configure the calendar overlay to do the following:

- Retrieve a calendar from Microsoft Exchange Online
- Display the calendar within the SharePoint Online calendar

In this scenario, information from the Exchange Online calendar isn't displayed in SharePoint Online. Additionally, you receive the following error message, which is displayed above the calendar:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic
>   Realm=""'.

Comment: So how can I fix that problem?